# Git verify changes brefore they committed to online repository?

Tags: git, push, bitbucket

I just started using Git VCS and I created repository on BitBucket when I pushed my project then I committed couple changes and pushed them to the remote repository.

Then I wanted to test how collaboration goes and created another user on BitBucket and added him to my main repository with read/write access to repository.

Then I renamed the user name and email in git bash and cloned the project with that new user credentials. However when I added commit and pushed it put it in online repository.

When I tried to only give read access it did not allow to push at all.

I thought you can see changes other users make and can either approve or reject them from main account (account who owns repository) before they added to master repository, **how can I set that up?**

**EDIT:** I am super admin and I have 3 random developers working for me developing my project. How can I check the code they created before allowing it to be written on my repository on BitBucket? So if I don't like the code I can reject it and make them come up with better one. – John Smith 24 secs ago

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? Wait, what *is* the question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I could not understand what are you tring to archieve. Ca you elaborate better on a question, stating what do you expect to heppen and what is happening?

Comment: By your text, I think you gave only read access to the repo and the user cant push. This is the expected behavior. What are you wanting to archieve?

Comment: Okay say i am super admin and i have 3 random developers working for me developing my project. How can i check the code they created before allowing it to be written on my repository on BitBucket?

So if i dont like the code i can reject it and make them come up with better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you give someone read only access then of course they can only pull, not push.

In your scenario you workflow would be...

User B does some work and commits locally
User B contacts User A (email whatever) and notifies that he has changes
User A pulls from User B and verifies correctness
User A pushes User B's changes to Bitbucket.

(User A must have set up User B as a remote)

Comment: Gr8 explanation, however when i log in as user B and go to repo of user A and click on create pull request i dont see any option to create pull request.

Comment: Guess by "User B does some work and commits locally" you mean he commits it in his repository on BitBucket not the one on his local machine?

Comment: Yes, he commits to his local repository on his machine. User A then pulls directly from User B's local machine.

Comment: I dont see option to create pull request in bitbucket when i login as user B

Comment: mmm, ok the Bitbucket pull request feature is doesn't work how I expected. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: How do i set another user as remote in git? i bet there's easier way just using pull request on bitbucket interface

Comment: Ok i found that you have to have new (or forked) repository on User B account in order for user B to create pull request trough bitbucket interface.

Comment: Yes he would have to create a forked repo This would be fine as an open source contributor, and a good workflow. But if User B is part of your team, but you just want to "gatekeep" him, its easier (imo) to just pull from him and push to the "blessed: repo. Remember Git is a distributed VCS, its designed for you to be able to pull from team members.

Comment: This way he must have his computer on 24/7 and in case of 10 hour time difference it might not be best to pull from his computer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you trying to archieve is to have the option to accept the changes made by other users to the repo. If this is the case, the user have tu use the `pull request` http://blog.bitbucket.org/2011/06/17/pull-request-revamp/